# Changing django model structure produces 1054 unkown column error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to change the `model` structure (column names) of an existing `Django` app that was already working and had a database.

**Original Files:**

The original `model.py` file was:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator

class Breed(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
            max_length=200,
            validators=[MinLengthValidator(2, "Breed must be greater than 1 character")]
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Cat(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(
            max_length=200,
            validators=[MinLengthValidator(2, "Nickname must be greater than 1 character")]
    )
    weight = models.FloatField()
    food = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    breed = models.ForeignKey('Breed', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nickname
```

and the original `/templates/cats/cat_list.html` file was:

```
{% extends "base_bootstrap.html" %}

{% block content %}   <h1>Cat List</h1>   {% if cat_list %}   <ul>
    {% for cat in cat_list %}
      <li>
          {{ cat.nickname }} ({{ cat.breed }})
          (<a href="{% url 'cats:cat_update' cat.id %}">Update</a> |
          <a href="{% url 'cats:cat_delete' cat.id %}">Delete</a>) <br/>
          {{ cat.weight }} ({{ cat.food }} food)
      </li>
    {% endfor %}   </ul>   {% else %}
    <p>There are no cats in the library.</p>   {% endif %}   <p>
    {% if breed_count > 0 %}
      <a href="{% url 'cats:cat_create' %}">Add a cat</a>
    {% else %}
      Please add a breed before you add a cat.
    {% endif %}   </p>   <p>   <a href="{% url 'cats:breed_list' %}">View breeds</a> ({{ breed_count }}) |
    <a href="{% url 'cats:breed_create' %}">Add a breed</a>   </p> {% endblock %}
```

**Desired Change:**

I am trying to change:

- weight >> age
- food >> colour

**What I Did:**

I made the two substitutions in the files above.  I deleted the `0001_initial.py` from the `/migrations` folder.

[image]

I then (1) `check` for syntax errors, (2) `makemigrations`; (3) `migrate` as per below:

[image]

**Error:**

I get an error in the template rendering where it says the column `cats_cat.age` is unknown.

[image]

**Additional sources:**

I have looked at a few things on the internet including:

1. [Django Models (1054, “Unknown column in 'field list'”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073550/django-models-1054-unknown-column-in-field-list)
2. [Django Models (1054, "Unknown column in 'field list'")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787237/django-models-1054-unknown-column-in-field-list)
3. [No such column error in Django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383978/no-such-column-error-in-django-models)

But cannot work out how to fix this error...

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted any migrations, but just created a new one with makemigrations, and applied it.

Comment: Your database now says the initial migration has been applied, but the contents of that migration, ie the resulting database columns, are not the same.

Comment: If you have the possibility to get the earlier version of your 0001 migration back (eg from Git), the easiest is to do that, then makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate, you helped a lot.  I will accept the answer if you did want to write it up.

Comment: Sure, copied into an answer. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have deleted any migrations, but just created a new one with makemigrations, and applied it.

Your database now says the initial migration has been applied, but the contents of that migration, ie the resulting database columns, are not the same.

If you have the possibility to get the earlier version of your 0001 migration back (eg from Git), the easiest is to do that, then makemigrations and migrate.

You can also just edit the physical structure of your database manually to match the migration, but that's manual work...